# Rails paperclip - Attach multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, attachment

I'm trying to attach with paperclip a multiple number of images to a component.
As this tutorial
http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/multiple-file-upload-with-rails-3-2-paperclip-html5-and-no-javascript

I have the following files:

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
   <%= file_field_tag('component_images_photo', multiple: true, name: "component[images_attributes][][photo]") %>
</div> 
<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

component.rb

```
has_many :images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :photo_file_name

    belongs_to :component
    has_attached_file :photo
end
```

The image model has been created as:

```
rails generate model image
```

And the paperclip attachment:

```
rails g paperclip image photo
```

By this time I get the following error when trying to create a component:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image_attributes
```

Maybe should I forget something in the model and paperclip calls?

**EDIT:**
Should I created the image model as:

```
rails generate model image component:references
```

??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `attr_accessible :images_attributes` to `component.rb`.

Comment: Ok, after add this, I get the following error:
`unknown attribute: image_attributes`
And if I write it like `attr_accessible :images_attributes` (realise that I'm using plural), it throws me `unknown attribute: component_id`.
Should I store a component id somewhere?